# Dashboards and Visualisations gets lost when Grafana restarts on DC/OS

Tags: grafana, prometheus, dcos

I have used [this documentation](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/metrics/prometheus/) in order to deploy Prometheus with Grafana on the cluster.
The problem arises whenever we restart our Prometheus and Grafana with some changed configuration all our dashboards and visualizations are gone.

Is there a workaround where we can persist the dashboards and visualizations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define volumes, which will be used in the Grafana/Prometheus containers to store data persistently.
Doc: https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.7/administration/storage/mount-disk-resources/

Comment: Agreed, though https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/storage/ has the most current storage options (1.7 isn't supported any longer and storage options have matured since then).